# Compute the chromatic polynomial of the $n$-cycle graph, i.e., the only connected graph on $n$ vertices each of which has degree $2$.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Compute the chromatic polynomial of the $n$-cycle graph, i.e., the only connected
graph on $n$ vertices each of which has degree $2$.

I can only think of how to compute this recursively. That is, using the fact that
$$p_G(k)=p_{G-e}(k)-p_{G/e}(k)$$
where $p_G{k}$ is the chromatic polynomial of $G,$ who has some edge $e$, $G-e$ is the graph obtained by the deletion of $e$, and $G/e$ is the graph obtained by the contraction of $e$, we can see that for some $n$-cycle
$$p_{G-e}(k)=\text{some tree on }n \text{ vertices}\\p_{G/e}(k)=\{\text{a }(n-1) \text{-cycle}\}$$
We know that a tree on $n$ vertices has chromatic polynomial
$$p_{G-e}(k)=k(k-1)^{n-1}$$
we can then use this same trick for $p_{G/e}(k)$, and then again and again, eventually recursively building our desired polynomial. I'm not sure this is what was intended for this exercise, as my professor made it seem like we should have some closed formula. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_n$ be the chromatic polynomial of the $n$-cycle; then $$p_n = k(k-1)^{n-1} - p_{n-1}.$$
If we set $q_n = (-1)^n p_n$, then multiply the recurrence above by $(-1)^n$, we get
$$
   q_n = -k(1-k)^{n-1} + q_{n-1} \implies q_n = q_3 + \sum_{i=4}^n -k(1-k)^{i-1} 
$$
which we can solve for $q_n$, because the sum is just a finite geometric series and $q_3 = -p_3 = -k(k-1)(k-2)$. This gives us a closed form for $p_n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that does not involve a sum, note for some simple cases of $n$ what the chromatic polynomial is. For instance,
$$n=2 \implies p_G(k)=k(k-1)=(k-1)^2+(k-1)\\n=3\implies p_G(k)=k(k-1)(k-2)=(k-1)^3-(k-1)\\n=4 \implies p_G(k)=k(k-1)(k^2-3k+3)=(k-1)^4+(k-1)$$
you can then prove by induction on $n$ that the chromatic polynomial of any $n$-cycle is$$p_G(k)=(k-1)^n+(-1)^n(k-1)$$